# Why does my Picture Box move to the top of the form?

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

So within my program, I want an object to move left or right depending on what arrow key is held down. I moved the the picture box on the bottom of them form so when any of the two arrow keys are pressed they would move along the bottom. But what's happening is when I press either key, the picture box goes to the top and moves left and right there. I don't know why this is.

Here's the code for the Form1, ignore the code for Form2; that's for experimentation purpose right now:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Move
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public int lives = 0;

    Form2 menu = new Form2();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        int i;

        for (i = 0; i < 500; i++)
        {

            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left)
            {
                pictureBox1.Location =  new Point(pictureBox1.Left - 1);
                Application.DoEvents();
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
            }

            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right)
            {
                pictureBox1.Location = new Point(pictureBox1.Left + 1);
                Application.DoEvents();
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
            }

            var rect1 = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(pictureBox1.Location, pictureBox1.Size);
            var rect2 = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(pictureBox2.Location, pictureBox2.Size);

            if (rect1.IntersectsWith(rect2))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Game Over!");
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                Application.Exit();
            }


            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down)
            {
                this.Hide();
                menu.Show();



            }
        }


    }
}

}
```

Comment: A point typically takes 2 arguments.  If you don't pass the second, it evidently defaults to 0.  y = 0 is the top of your windows form.  Change your new points to `new Point(pictureBox1.Left +/- 1, pictureBox1.Top)`.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
pictureBox1.Location =  new Point(pictureBox1.Left - 1, pictureBox1.Top);
```

and

```
pictureBox1.Location = new Point(pictureBox1.Left + 1, pictureBox1.Top);
```

respectively to specify the currently used Y coordinate.

When using the constructor of `Point` that takes only one value, the system expects this one value to contain both the X and Y coordinates (As higher and lower word of the value) and will use 0 for the Y coordinate because the X values you use are so low that the higher word of the value is 0.

Comment: thanks for the advice, I was skeptical of what was wrong with it and you reassured me!